# Different behavior with the same regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex wich is supposed to check for allowed characters in HTTP headers. I use it for testing string that will be slugified.

My problem is, when I use the literal version I obtain a different result from the Object version of the Regex :

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/JosselinTD/tkxhk6fn/

```
var regexObject = new RegExp("^[A-z\u00C0-\u00ff\u0180-\u024f0-9\s'\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*\-_~\|`+]+$", "gi");
var regexLiteral = /^[A-z\u00C0-\u00ff\u0180-\u024f0-9\s'\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*\-_~\|`+]+$/gi;

var stringTest = 'HackForGood 2016 - León'; // More strings in the fiddle

alert('Test with object : ' + regexObject.test(stringTest) + '\nTest with literal : ' + regexLiteral.test(stringTest));
```

Is there a reason for the difference in behavior ?

Comment: `\s` and `\-` in the first regex get stripped from the escapes and match `s` and `\*\-_` turns into a range, `*-_`

Comment: Damn... Not only those two, every `\` in the string ends in nothing, so my regex fail. Thanks !

Comment: Those two are important, others may be removed from both patterns.